# need help initialized Vuetify into my vue-cli 3

Tags: vue.js, nginx, webpack, vuetify.js

I need help pre-rendering my site.  So at first, I had a fully functional site. I wanted to add pre-render-spa plugin to the server. but everything got ruined. I needed to update the Vuetify framework too. and that messed it all up. Got a lot of errors but managed to deploy the server but when I do I get this "Vuetify is not properly initialized," so I need help initialized the new Vuetify into my CLI 3 vue.
My Main.js File.

Main.js

```
import Vue from "vue";
import './plugins/vuetify'
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
import store from "./store";
import './assets/style.css';
var VueScrollTo = require('vue-scrollto');
import VueAnalytics from "vue-analytics";

import VueLazyload from 'vue-lazyload'

Vue.use(VueLazyload, {
  preLoad: 1.3,
  attempt: 1,
  observer: true,
})


Vue.use(VueScrollTo)
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.use(VueAnalytics, {
  id: "UA-89031274-11",
  autoTracking: {
    screenview: true
  }
});
new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  mounted: () => document.dispatchEvent(new Event("x-app-rendered")),
  render: function (h) {
      return h(App);
  },
}).$mount("#app");
```

vue.config.js

```
const path = require("path");
const PrerenderSPAPlugin = require("prerender-spa-plugin");
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const VuetifyLoaderPlugin = require('vuetify-loader/lib/plugin')

module.exports.plugins.push = {
  configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: "./index.html",
        inject: false
      }),
      new PrerenderSPAPlugin({
        staticDir: path.join(__dirname, './dist'),
        routes: ["/"]
      }),
      new VuetifyLoaderPlugin()
    ]
  }
};
```

vuetify.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'
import 'vuetify/src/styles/main.sass'

Vue.use(Vuetify);


export default new Vuetify({
  icons: {
    iconfont: 'mdi'
  },
})
```

So this is all the file that come to relate with the pre-rendering and vuetify. I tried to reinstall vuetify and vue-cli and `npm install` nothing has fixed the problem that vuetify is not loading.
I saw that vuetify updated their installing documents and they said to include `vuetify` before the `$mount("#app");`
in this case the build just keep going forever and doesn't stop.

```
new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  vuetify,
  mounted: () => document.dispatchEvent(new Event("x-app-rendered")),
  render: function (h) {
      return h(App);
  },
}).$mount("#app");
```

Greatful for the help.

Answer (score 0):

In `main.js` changed

```
import './plugins/vuetify'
```

to

```
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify'**
```

and then add it into new `Vue` instance like this:

```
new Vue({
...
  vuetify,
...
}).$mount('#app')
```

for example, `main.js`:

```
    import Vue from 'vue'
    import App from './App.vue'
    import router from './router'
    import store from './store'
    import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify'
    import 'material-design-icons-iconfont/dist/material-design-icons.css'
    Vue.config.productionTip = false
    new Vue({
      router,
      store,
      vuetify,
      render: h => h(App)
    }).$mount('#app')
```

and `vuetify.js`:

```
    import Vue from 'vue'
    import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
    import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'
    import colors from 'vuetify/es5/util/colors'

    Vue.use(Vuetify)

    export default new Vuetify({
      iconfont: 'md',
      theme: {
        primary: colors.green.darken1,
        secondary: colors.green.lighten4,
        accent: colors.green.darken3
      }
    })
```